# Https Subdomain Redirect to Http root domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Hello I have a subdomain 
`Https://apple.example.com` 
That I want to redirect to 
`Http://example.com`

I tried to write on htaccess of the subdomain this code that I have found on some old question but it's not working

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.yourdomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www\.yourdomain\.com/subdomain/$1 [L]
```

Any help thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =apple.example.com
RewriteRule ^ http://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It's still not working, maybe my case is different. I have bought the domain on GoDaddy and found out that a subdomain was still indexed with HTTPS. I have recreated the subdomain and tried to redirect to the main domain without the SSL certificate. The main domain is working properly too, even the HTTP version of the subdomain is not redirecting

Comment: I would check that the subdomain is being served from where you think it is. Put a page there and make sure it appears when you visit it. The above code will work as long as it's in the right place and it's all set up properly.